# Create array of INT's from 0 to a variable

Tags: c#, visual-studio, console-application

So I have a program where you basically enter a number, for example, if you enter 50 an array gets created that includes numbers from 0 to 50. The number entered will always be random and I'm wondering if it is possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

sure, here you go

```
int To = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine()); //read a entered number from console and parse it
int[] array = Enumerable.Range(0, To + 1).ToArray(); //create a array from 0 to the number
```

Comment: _"enter a number"_ - imo the random generator is in front of the screen

Comment: you are right, I guess the "random" number is for the input number, and not the actual array's elements. But why should one use `Enumerable.Range` and why not simply `int[] array = new int[50];` ?

Comment: OP mentioned that he wants a array _that includes numbers from 0 to 50_

Comment: I need coffee  and + 1:)

Answer (score -2):

If you needed to generate `n` random numbers between 0-50, then you could use the [`Console.ReadLine()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.readline(v=vs.110).aspx) method to read in the number of elements that you wish to generate and then the [`Enumerable.Range`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.range(v=vs.100).aspx) method to instantiate and seed the random number generation :

```
var elements = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine()); 
var random = Enumerable.Range(0, elements).Select(x => new Random(x).Next(0,50)).ToArray();
```

You can [see an example of this in action here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/KzOqIS).

Otherwise, if you don't need the numbers to be random, the [`Enumerable.Range`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.range(v=vs.100).aspx) method on it's own should be sufficient :

```
var elements = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine()); 
var values = Enumerable.Range(0, elements + 1).ToArray();
```